# What do people use Elasticsearch for?

Tags: php, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am wondering what peoples use case is for using Elasticsearch. I am started a social networking site that will have places, vets, people, pets, pet shops etc.

How would Elasticsearch help me in this type of search, as I need to search all necessary collections and rows.

Comment: This can be closed, per the official posting guidelines, as Too Broad or Primarily Opinion Based.

Answer (score 1):

You may create endless report with the help of logstash, logstash forwarder, and Kibana plugin. For example a heatmap to display geographical location of the user, an historical line chart to display total number of activities of the day, most favourite topic of the day, week, or month, chart to display most active user, topic etc, user's demographic interest etc.

Comment: How does elasticsearch know that I am using mongodb (v3.2) and what do I need to do to make sure everything a user searches (in search bar) is recorded - we want to find out most search (vets, companies, businesses, people, pets, etc)

but also show what is trending based on #tags like Twitter

Comment: It is just a matter of your application design. I would recommend to explore logstash, and logstash forwarder.  You may get more information from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html, https://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/12/06/use-lumberjack-logstash-forwarder-to-forward-logs-logstash/, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-lumberjack.html

Comment: Now logstash forwarder has been changed to FILEBEAT